# Starting chrome with flags does not show up as enabled in chrome://flags

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

Trying to launch chrome with "Disable hardware-accelerated video decode" enabled.

I have been testing the command:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --disable-accelerated-video-decode
```

When chrome opens and I check chrome://flags, "Disable hardware-accelerated video decode" shows as disabled (should be enabled)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify that the command line argument was correctly set, use `chrome://version`. Transient command line flags won’t show up as set under `chrome://flags`.

Comment: I can see "--disable-accelerated-video-decode" in chrome://version. It would be nice to know that it actually enabled that flag, because you can pass in anything. For example, I can pass in --hot-dog, and it will still show up.

Comment: Are we talking about Chrome in Desktop or Android/iOS mobile? Cause in Mobile we do not easyly have command line, how do we do that similar in Tablet/Mobile devices?